# Grouping results from 2 tables with MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I think this might be more a PHP thing than SQL as the results I have are correct. My mind is just blank as to how to achieve the formatting I need.

I have two tables:

```
privilege;
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| privilege_id       | bigint(20)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| privilege_group_id | bigint(20)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| privilege_name     | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

privilege_group;
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| privilege_group_id   | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| privilege_group_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to output the reqult of my query like this:

**Privilege Group Name**

- Privilege Group 1
- Privilege Group 2

**Another Privilege Group Name**

- Another Privilege Group 1
- Another Privilege Group 2

My query returns the correct results:

```
SELECT privilege_group.privilege_group_name, privilege.privilege_name FROM privilege LEFT JOIN privilege_group ON privilege.privilege_group_id = privilege_group.privilege_group_id ORDER BY privilege_group.privilege_group_id ASC
```

I am just not too sure how to disregard the privilege group name after the first result for each child. e.g. I get this:

**Privilege Group Name**

- Privilege Group 1

**Privilege Group Name**

- Privilege Group 2

**Another Privilege Group Name**

- Another Privilege Group 1

**Another Privilege Group Name**

- Another Privilege Group 2

I know I can achieve this with 2 queries looped, but the above returns the right data and I just can't figure how to process it!

Edit:

```
      <?php
  try {

$rnum = ''; 
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT privilege_group.privilege_group_name,privilege.privilege_name
FROM privilege
LEFT JOIN privilege_group ON privilege.privilege_group_id = privilege_group.privilege_group_id
ORDER BY privilege_group.privilege_group_id ASC");          
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $rnum++;

// I know I need some conditional around this to only show it once per group!
if () {  
echo "<b>$row[privilege_group_name]</b><br />";
//
}
  echo "$row[privilege_name]<br />"; 

} 
  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage();
exit();
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Can you also include your PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add `privilege_group.privilege_group_id` to your `SELECT` statement, then:

```
<?php
  try {
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare(
        "SELECT privilege_group.privilege_group_id,
             privilege_group.privilege_group_name,
             privilege.privilege_name
         FROM privilege
         LEFT JOIN privilege_group ON
             privilege.privilege_group_id = privilege_group.privilege_group_id
         ORDER BY privilege_group.privilege_group_id ASC");

    $last_group_id = -1;

    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      if ($last_group_id != $row['privilege_group_id']) {
        echo "<b>" . $row['privilege_group_name'] . "</b><br />";
        $last_group_id = $row['privilege_group_id'];
      }
      echo $row['privilege_name'] . "<br />";
    }
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error : '. $e->getMessage();
    exit();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I got there with your initial reply - thanks you very much. I will be doing more complex formatting, separating the group from it's children without 2 looped queries was the main aim.